# The (.+?) in Python

Tags: python, regex

What does `(.+?)` mean in Python? I am trying to figure it out but I couldn't find any results. Can you tell me what it does?

I think `(.+?)` refers to a unknown thing, but I am not sure.

Comment: Please give us an example of where you've seen this in code or text.

Comment: Lookup regular expressions and go from there.

Comment: [that is regular expression syntax](http://regex101.com)

Answer (score 2):

That looks like it might be a regular expression. You can learn more about them here: [Python Regular Expressions.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

That particular regular expression (without the `?`) would match an entire line because the `'.'` represents any character besides the newline character and the + allows for any number of repetitions. `+?` makes the `'+'` 'non-greedy', so as few characters as possible will be matched.

I can't imagine a use for this particular regex without a context. It will basically return the first non-new-line character.